# Spark's RDD.map() will not execute unless the item inside RDD is visited

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm not quite sure about how `Scala` and `Spark` works, maybe I write the code in the wrong way.

The function I want to achieve is, for a given `Seq[String, Int]`, assign a random item in `v._2.path` to `_._2`.

To do that, I implement a method and call this method in the next line

```
def getVerticesWithFeatureSeq(graph: Graph[WikiVertex, WikiEdge.Value]): RDD[(VertexId, WikiVertex)] = {
  graph.vertices.map(v => {
    //For each token in the sequence, assign an article to them based on its path(root to this node)
    println(v._1+" before "+v._2.featureSequence)
    v._2.featureSequence = v._2.featureSequence.map(f => (f._1, v._2.path.apply(new scala.util.Random().nextInt(v._2.path.size))))
    println(v._1+" after "+v._2.featureSequence)
    (v._1, v._2)
  })
}

val dt = getVerticesWithFeatureSeq(wikiGraph)
```

When I execute it, I suppose the `println` should print out something, but it didn't.
If I add another line of code

```
dt.foreach(println)
```

`println` inside `map` will print correctly.

Is there some latency of spark's code execution? Like if no one is accessing a variable, the computing will be deferred or even canceled?

Comment: Please show your Vertex class

Comment: Is vertices an RDD? That would explain your issue, since Spark transformations are lazy until no action is executed, foreach in this case. See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-operations for a complete list of transformations and actions.

Comment: @jaranda would you move that into an answer? I think that's the case.

Comment: @maasg I've just provided my answer :)

Comment: Don't recommend `println`s inside distributed MR type frameworks like Spark and Hadoop - they usually won't end up coming back to your console but output in some log somewhere on the node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is `graph.vertices` an RDD? That would explain your issue, since Spark transformations are lazy until no action is executed, `foreach` in your case:

```
val dt = getVerticesWithFeatureSeq(wikiGraph) //no result is computed yet, map transformation is 'recorded'
dt.foreach(println) //foreach action requires a result, this triggers the computation
```

RDD's remember the transformations applied and they are only computed when an action requires a result to be returned to the driver program.

You can check http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-operations for further details and a list of available transformations and actions.

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#printing-elements-of-an-rdd
Please take note around printing elements of an RDD. It is safer to collect() then print out, rather than do a foreach() Otherwise on a cluster the statements will be printed on multiple machines.